# Do Russian prefixes embody event structures?

Tags: semantics, лингвистика

Considering words (nominals, verbs and adjectives) we can notice that lexical items derived from a same stem (e.g. ***-лив-/-лит-***) like *полив, разлив, перелив, вылить, долить, отлить,* etc. suggest certain actions pertinent to some liquid.

Again, considering words with same prefixes, like *почёт, помощь, побег, поступь, познать, разнос, раздрай, размазать,* etc. we notice that they imply certain scenarios: surficial distribution (***po-***) or centripetal perfective/telic/progressive distribution (***raz-***).

The question is, whether these event scenarios, or event structures, are defined by semantics of the words, or by the prefixes.

Comment: Помощь and поддержка have different prefixes. По- definitely has just perfective meaning, compare получить, поесть, and пойти - there's no "surficial distribution" meaning in these verbs. I suggest you reformulate the question, narow it, and specify which prefixes you're interested in.

Comment: OK, that might be a separate question then.

Comment: prefixes in Russian verbs play the same role as prepositions in English verbs: ask about - спросить, ask for - попросить, so both words and prefixes take part in semantics.

Answer (score 4):

There are too many aspects here to answer briefly. Consider just one prefix, "по":

> **Значение**
>
> - *с наречиями*: словно, как, т.е. указывает на подобие. *по-мужски*
> - *с наречиями и прилагательными* указывает на сравнительную степень.    *побольше, поменьше*.
> - *с глаголами и их производными*: указывает на завершение действия с полным или частичным охватом: *позавтракать, покончить*
> - *с глаголами и их производными*: указывает на совершение действия в течение некоторого времени: *покрутить, порубить, походить*
> - *с глаголами и их производными*: указывает на начало движения: *поехать, поползти, поплыть*
> - *с глаголами и их производными*: указывает на приобретение признака: *побагроветь, побелеть, позеленеть*
> - *с глаголами и их производными*: указывает на действие, произведенное в значительном количестве или объёме, одновременно
>     придавая пренебрежительный оттенок: *понаехать, поразбросать,
>     пораскидать*
> - ... etc

(from [ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/по-](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE-))

Comment: Спасибо за форматирование, @Александр!

Comment: Рада помочь. Добро пожаловать на сайт тоже! :)

Answer (score 2):

The semantics is defined by the both prefixes and words. Some words from your example allow to use any of the prefixes with different meanings. For example:

```
- помазать (anoint) and размазать (smear) are 2 different actions
- побег (escape, runaway) and разбег (running start) 
  are 2 different nouns which come from бег
```